# How to check collision for multiple symbols

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was wondering if it was possible to check for collision by the instance name and not separate mc names. I have about 150-200 objects (dots for pacman game) that I need to check collision for and want to do it efficently. Thanks!

Comment: Yes certainly possible. I hope you are not naming each dot `dot1`...etc all the way up to `dot200`. How are you adding them to the stage?

Comment: I have a mc with instance dot in my library. @TaylorSwift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have instance named dots, and a player, you could do something like this:

```
//a var to hold each loop iteration's dot for convenience
var tmpDot:DisplayObject;

//loop 200 times from 1 - 200
for(var i:int=1;i<= 200;i++){
    //getChildByName gets an instance from a string, in this case dot plus i (i is the current iteration number)
    tmpDot = getChildByName("dot" + i);

    //check if the dot exists and is hitting the player
    if(tmpDot && tmpDot.hitTestObject(player)){
        //hit a dot, do something here like remove the dot
        removeChild(tmpDot);
        //increment points etc.

        //if there's no possibility of the player hitting more than one dot at a time, then for efficiency you should break out of this loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, as mentioned in the comments on your question, giving 200 dots an instance name is tedious.  An easier way, would be to take your dot MovieClip in your library, go to it's properties, and export it for actionscript (let's say you gave it a class name of `Dot`).  Then what you could do, is at the start of a level find all the dot objects that you have on your timeline (no instance names needed) and add them to an array:

```
//DO THIS ONLY WHEN THE LEVEL STARTS

//create a vector/array to store all your dots for better speed
var allDots:Vector.<Dot> = new Vector.<Dot>();

//iterate over all the children of this timeline frame
for(var i:int=0;i<numChildren;i++){
    //if the item is a Dot, add it to the array
    if(getChildAt(i) is Dot){
        allDots.push(getChildAt(i) as Dot);
    }
}
```

Now, you can do the hit tests like this:

```
//YOU PROBABLY WANT TO DO THIS EITHER EVERY FRAME, OR WHENEVER THE PLAYER MOVES

//flag to see if all dots are eaten
var allEaten:Boolean = true;
var tmpDot:Dot;

for(var i:int=0;i<allDots.length;i++){
    tmpDot = allDots[i];

    //.... same as the top code example at this point
    if(tmpDot && tmpDot.hitTestObject(player)){
        removeChild(tmpDot);
        //do anything else you need to do when a dot is eaten

        //if we've already determined that we haven't eaten all the dots, then break the loop
        if(!allEaten) break;
    }

    //if a dot has a parent, then they haven't been all eaten
    if(tmpDot.parent){
        allEaten = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has actually been the most help, thank you very much +1, but I am having troubles wrapping my head around how to add them to the array, anyway thanks!